# Define Mongoose Schema model with Typescript using Typings

Tags: typescript, mongoose, typing

After upgrading my app from tsd to typings for typescript everything worked fine except the mongoose models. I can't figure how to configure the new changes, tried several methods but they seem to work. I lost the save and other methods set on the model by extending it with mongoose.Model. Here is how i had the setup before the breaking changes

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
import {NextFunction} from 'express';
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
    username: string;
    password: string;

    authenticate(password: string): boolean;
    findUniqueUsername(username: string, suffix: number, next: NextFunction): void;
}

interface IUserModel extends mongoose.Model<IUser> {
    hashPassword(password: string): string;
}

var UserSchema: mongoose.Schema = new Schema({
    username: {
       type: String,        
       required: 'Please fill in the user name',
       unique: true
    },
    password: {
       type: String
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function (password) {...};
UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function (password) {...};
UserSchema.statics.findUniqueUsername = function (username, suffix, next) {...};

var User = <IUserModel> mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

export {IUser, IUserModel, User}
```

I am also getting an error:

> An interface may only extend a class or another" for the IUserModel
>   extends mongoose.Modelinterface.

This all worked great fine until I changed to using Typings. Whats the new way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. I just installed the mongoose typings with typings install --save mongoose. The only caveat maybe is that the dependencies of this one external module seem to be a bit off, as it needs NodeJS types. Just typings install --save --global env~node should fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i got it to work by using the old mongoose tsd files, the new Typings file would not work for me even when i added node/mongoose-promise/mongodb/ect .